# Taxes return fraud

Tags: scams, fraud

My ex used my social security number to fill his taxes and now he owed back I got me holding back $80,000 in taxes but do I do I need help

Comment: Who filed your tax return reporting these income? Did you file it? Did your ex file it? Did you know about it? You should probably talk to an attorney and potentially law enforcement (especially if you knew nothing about it).